# how to create multiple divs(createElement) in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there any solution to build **multiple divs with in div** in PURE JavaScript ?

**jQuery version**

```
 for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
     $('#maindiv').append('<div id="page' + i + '">new divs</ div>')
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Lnw/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the same as your original jQuery snippet, in that it adds `divs` to the end of, and inside your original div.

```
 mainDiv = document.getElementById( 'maindiv' );
 for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
     mainDiv.innerHTML += '<div id="page' + i + '">new divs</ div>';
 }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Lnw/197/

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the `+=` operator for appending `innerHTML` attribute?

Comment: This is adding an id (I assume you mean that, and not a name, which is something else).  They're the same as the ones you created page1, page2, page3.

Comment: @MaciejSz That's fair enough.  Though probably not a big deal - updated.

Comment: @RobBaillie: probably not, but I like to keep the code as clean as possible.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/5yYxU/

To append `div`'s (not text) use this:

```
var pageLimit=30;

var parentDiv = document.getElementById('test');
for (var i = 1; i < pageLimit; i++ ) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.innerHTML = 'Testing';
    parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
var newHtml = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      newHtml += '<div id="page' + i + '">new divs</ div>';
 }
document.getElementById("maindiv").innerHTML = newHtml;
```

byee

Comment: Building the whole string first is more efficient +1

Comment: thx, I build the string because is the only way to use **+=** ;)

Comment: Operating on strings is always less efficient (not to mention unclean and inflexible) then using the OO interface.

Comment: really? thx... however bboymaanu has used string then i use it myself. However thx

Comment: Yea, it's common for young developers. When they learn about the world of strings they just stop there. It is true, that many tasks can be done with them, but honestly - why the great minds that come up with OO would even bother if it was the ultimate solution? For me it is just like being stuck on 2nd gear.

Comment: right... But not despise young developer... I'm (we're) here also for learn... :) enjoy your day.

Comment: @MaciejSz Just to clarify, I was comparing this answer to the accepted answer and my own answer, which modify innerHTML many times - building the whole string first then modifying innerHTML once is more efficient than that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Lnw/195/

```
var div = document.getElementById('test');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<div></div>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Looking solution with pure `JavaScript` without using `jQuery`

Comment: @Zword notice that the fiddle is inserting text, yet the OPs question wants to insert `div` elements.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan its just simple.Replace text with the div code

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.getElementById('divId');

for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++ )
{
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.innerHTML = 'My new div';
    div.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

**[appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)** Add a div to the end of the list of children of a specified parent div.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var div = document.getElementById('maindiv');
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    div.innerHTML += '<div id="page' + i + '">new divs</ div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> use this:
>
> for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
>
> document.getElementById("h-related").innerHTML ='new divs'
>   }

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using document fragments.

```
var maindiv = document.getElementById('maindiv');
var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.id = 'page' + i;
  docfrag.appendChild(newdiv);
}

maindiv.appendChild(docfrag)
```